# set-fact a var with a dict value from a specific key

Tags: ansible

I have a dict like from a debug task :

```
ok: [node] => {
    "_res": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "msg": {
            "ansible_architecture": "64 bits", 
            "ansible_bios_date": "11/26/2012", 
            "ansible_bios_version": "Hyper-V UEFI Release v1.0", 
            "ansible_date_time": { ...
```

when I check the type :

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var:  mydict | type_debug

ok: [node] => {
"mydict | type_debug": "dict"
}
```

And I would like to affect for example the value of ansible_bios_version to a new fact.

I have tried already :

```
- name: set facts
  set_fact:
    var: mydict | map(attribute='ansible_bios_version') | list
    var: mydict |selectattr("ansible_bios_version", "defined")|list|length >0
    var: mydict | selectattr("ansible_bios_version")|list
    ....
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If *mydict* is as follows

```
  mydict:
    _res:
      changed: false
      failed: false
      msg:
        ansible_architecture: 64 bits
        ansible_bios_date: 11/26/2012
        ansible_bios_version: Hyper-V UEFI Release v1.0
        ansible_date_time: ansible_date_time
```

then the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    bios_ver: "{{ mydict._res.msg.ansible_bios_version }}"
- debug:
    var: bios_ver
```

give

```
bios_ver: Hyper-V UEFI Release v1.0
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that's the result, something I haven't said is that my dict come from a lookup like :  **{{ lookup('redis', 'ansible_node')}}**  And I didn't manage to do something like : **bios_ver: "{{ lookup('redis', 'ansible_node').ansible_bios_version }}"**